# How to show the following series diverge or converge if we assume $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty}a_k=0$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

For $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {a_k^2}$, $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {\sqrt{|a_k|}}$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {\frac{a_k}{k}}$, if i understand the question correctly. I think we can give both convergent and divergent examples for the last two, but the first one i think is definitely convergent.

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {\frac{a_k}{k}}$: since $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty}a_k=0$, the nominator has lower degree than denominator and so $a_n=\frac{n}{k^p}$ for $p\gt 0$. Therefore $\frac{a_k}{k}=\frac{n}{k^{p+1}}$ for $p+1\gt 1$. So $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {\frac{a_k}{k}}$ has to converge.

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {a_k^2}$: if we let $a_k=\frac{1}{k}$, then $a_k^2=\frac{1}{k^2}$ converges by $p$-series. But if $a_k=\frac{1}{k^{\frac 12}}$, then $a_k^2=\frac {1}{k}$ diverges

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {\sqrt{|a_k|}}$: if $a_k=\frac{1}{k^2}$, then $\sqrt{|a_k|}=\frac{1}{k}$ diverges . But if $a_k=\frac{1}{k^4}$, then $\sqrt{|a_k|}=\frac{1}{k^2}$ converges

I am suspicious of my answers. Could someone point out the mistakes?

Comment: The first one you dealt with (last in the given list) need not converge. For convenience start at $k=2$, and let $a_k=\frac{1}{\ln k}$. (We don't want to start at $k=0$ since then the first term involves division by $0$.)

Comment: So all of them can both diverge and converge?

Comment: For the last one, if we assume that $\sum_k a_k$ converges then certainly $\sum_k \tfrac{a_k}{k}$ converges and we still can't ensure that the first two converge.

Comment: @CoolKid: Yes, the condition $a_k\to 0$ is not enough to give convergence in any of the $3$ cases. In your examples, modifications are needed to avoid dividing by $0$.